# Django middleware using Django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-middleware

Is it possible to use regular Django models from within Middleware?

I have been looking for simple examples but couldn't find anything about the availability of such parts of the Django framework to middleware. I believe from my limited understanding that they should be.

Comment: Why not just *try it* and see? The world is not going to implode on itself if you try something and it doesn't work. At the very *worst* you'll get an error, and then you'll know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The model system is available from everywhere in your django application, as long as you import the relevant models. It is not tied to the HTTP lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i agree with @marcin you can use models anywhere, and as a reference you can look at [django flatpages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/flatpages/) middleware, there it took the decision which `flatpage` should be rendered.